# ngTagsInput- Add a Tag in a function

Tags: angularjs

I use [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) including the autosuggest-function and I want to add Tags also with a click-event, if the users click on a sidebar-menu (in addition to the direct input). All existing tags should still be there. I currently use a horrible hack. When the user clicks the first link and click the second link, everything works fine. From the Link 3, Link 1 and 2 are summarized in a day. Thank you for your Tipps

**HTML Tags Input**

```
<tags-input class="bootstrap" id="tagsInput"
        placeholder=""
        add-on-enter="true"
        addFromAutocompleteOnly="false"
        on-tag-added="tagAdded($tag)" 
        on-tag-removed="tagRemoved($tag)"
        ng-model="autosuggest"
        replace-spaces-with-dashes="false">
  <auto-complete source="loadAutosuggest($query)"
        select-first-match="false"
        min-length="0"
        debounce-delay="0"
        max-results="10">
  </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

**HTML Sidebar Menu with links**

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
   <li ng-repeat="item in icdItems">
     <a href="#" ng-attr-title="item.title" ng-click="getTitle(item.title)"><span>{{ item.name }}</span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getTitle = function(title) {

    var currentVal = $scope.autosuggest;
    if (currentVal == '') {
        $scope.autosuggest = [title];
    } else {
        var autosuggest = $scope.autosuggest;
        var textOnly = autosuggest.map(function(el){
             return el.text;
           }).join(", ");
        console.log($scope.autosuggest);
        $scope.autosuggest = [textOnly, title];
    };

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.k. I found a solution:

```
$scope.getTitle = function(title) { 
    var newTitle={'text':title};    
    $scope.autosuggest.push(newTitle);
    console.log($scope.autosuggest);
};
```